# JS / ANGULAR : set class variable value from a method callback

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Inside my Component ts file , I' ve a "connexion" method:

```
export class MyClass {
  isOpen = false

  openConnection(url) {

    this.socketClient.connect(this.tokenheader, (response) => {
        this.isOpen = true;
        this.getResponse()
      },
      this.errorCallBack
    );
  }

  errorCallBack(error) {
    this.isOpen = false; // CANNOT READ 'isopen' of undefined
    console.log("Connexion failure" + error);
  }
}
```

This method returns several callbacks for "response" and "error".

As you can see i ve the call of  **"this.errorCallBack"** when error

it's used to print the error message ;

but i ve **to set my class variable** to false `(this.isOpen = false;)`

but i get :

> CANNOT READ 'isopen' of undefined

**Sugesstions ??**

Comment: You can bind context `this` through `this.errorCallBack.bind(this)` instead of `this.errorCallback`

Comment: @yurzui cool ; that works

Comment: Please proof-read your question in the future, there's many typos, some of them in the code (such as `isopen` referenced in the error message) and it's unclear if they are actually related to your question or not.

Comment: Have a look at the other duplicate.